# Rails deploying to DigitalOcean with cap/passenger/ubuntu Failing at assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger, web-deployment

So, in deploying my Rails app to DigitalOcean using passenger and ubuntu I get the following debug error:

```
DEBUG [1252b854]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [1252b854]    ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token string «HydraCAD-R», expected punc «,» (line: 18866, col: 14, pos: 966080)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:11936)
    at js_error (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:12155)
    at croak (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:20622)
    at token_error (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:20759)
    at expect_token (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:20982)
    at expect (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:21120)
    at /tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:29716
    at /tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:21493
    at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:28884)
    at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:31652)
    at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2660:404)
    at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2660:496)
    at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2660:939)
    at expression (/tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2660:1252)
    at /tmp/execjs20160119-19094-sekf6gjs:2659:30214
DEBUG [1252b854]    new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2659:11936)
js_error ((execjs):2659:12155)
croak ((execjs):2659:20622)
token_error ((execjs):2659:20759)
expect_token ((execjs):2659:20982)
expect ((execjs):2659:21120)
(execjs):2659:29716
(execjs):2659:21493
expr_atom ((execjs):2659:28884)
maybe_unary ((execjs):2659:31652)
expr_ops ((execjs):2660:404)
maybe_conditional ((execjs):2660:496)
maybe_assign ((execjs):2660:939)
expression ((execjs):2660:1252)
(execjs):2659:30214
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/deploy/deployApp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
DEBUG [1252b854]    Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
DEBUG [1252b854]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using ruby -v
    ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]

All code has been pushed up to git.

I have tried precompiling with rake assets:precompile and then running git add ., commiting and pushing that to git.

Running locally I get:

```
bundle exec passenger start
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /Users/user/desktop/railsApps/railsApp/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /Users/user/desktop/railsApps/railsApp/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
Problems? Check https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/standalone/troubleshooting/
===============================================================================
App 40261 stderr: ruby-2.2.3 is not installed.
App 40261 stdout: To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.2.3'
App 40261 stdout:
App 40384 stdout:
```

Not sure what it is referring to having an unexpected token string «HydraCAD-R». Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try "rake assets:precompile -e production" on your local machine, it should give a detail error, which you receives on server, then it can help to trace error

Comment: That gives me an error running that script:
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `production' for #<Rake::Application:0x007fd1db01e758>

Comment: strange, How could you run your project locally on production server?

Comment: basically when i got compilation issue on server, i can easily got it in my local production server, so firstly i solve it on my local machine then make push to server

Comment: The project runs fine locally with no errors.

Comment: Though it does start by saying App 40261 stderr: ruby-2.2.3 is not installed.
App 40261 stdout: To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.2.3'. Which is odd since when I run 'ruby -v', it says ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14].

Comment: Yes, but their can be some errors on production related to css or js, so its easy to find on precompilation of assets on local production server.

Comment: oops it seems rvm issue now

Comment: please add all kind of descriptions in question, to resolve issue fast.

Comment: also add your ruby version in gemfile and push code to server

Comment: Still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, solved mine by restarting the droplet

Comment: I think I ended up having to change my production.rb environment file to have `config.assets.compile = false` and then I did a `rake assets:clobber` and `rake assets:precompile`.